Static files from alternative root location are not served, nginx tries to look for them in primary root location
I've been banging my head with this and just cannot seem to get it to work. I am trying to host my portfolio website, which is located in one folder (along with it's static files) and I have a separate folder where all my projects will be located in their own subfolders. The structure is below:
Root folder /var/www/html/
Portfolio location /var/www/html/portfolio/
Projects location /var/www/html/projects
The projects folder will contain all my projects, each in it's own subfolder. Currently there is one basic react app: /var/www/html/projects/personal-budget-app
My nginx configuration file nginx.conf has not been touched and refers to /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, which is below:
server {

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index-maintenance.html index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.mywebsite.com; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/portfolio;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

    location /personal-budget-app {
        root /var/www/html/projects;
}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


www.mywebsite.com/ works good and loads the portfolio website. However, when I try to go to www.mywebsite.com/personal-budget-app, the app gets partially loaded. I end up with a blank page, browser tab has react app name, so index.html was served from /var/www/html/projects/personal-budget-app, but static files located in /var/www/html/projects/personal-budget-app/static were not served and browser console throws 404 error that https://www.mywebsite.com/static/js/main.bd4a7d0e.js was not found.
When I check nginx error log, I see that the nginx is trying to find those files in /var/www/html/portfolio/static:
2024/04/03 11:27:47 [error] 6360#6360: *607 open() "/var/www/html/portfolio/static/js/main.bd4a7d0e.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /static/js/main.bd4a7d0e.js HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://www.mywebsite.com/personal-budget-app/"

2024/04/03 11:27:47 [error] 6360#6360: *607 open() "/var/www/html/portfolio/static/css/main.009c7e7b.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /static/css/main.009c7e7b.css HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://www.mywebsite.com/personal-budget-app/"

My understanding is that when I define root directory under the location /personal-budget-app {} block, nginx should serve everything from that root directory, including any static files that are in subfolders, linked in index.html, like <link href="/static/css/main.009c7e7b.css" rel="stylesheet">.
What am I missing here?
So far I have been succesfful in loading the react app by modifying the / location block to refer to the app directly:
location / {
     /var/www/html/projects/personal-budget-app;
}

The app fully loads with all static files
I was also able to load the app in original configuration by adding additional location block:
location /static {
     /var/www/html/projects/personal-budget-app;
}

But this would cause problems once I start adding more projects that have static files located in their own /static folders, so it is not really a solution.
I also seem to have no issues accessing files directly by typical full path into address bar, for example https://www.mywebsite.com/personal-budget-app/static/js/main.bd4a7d0e.js.
